# SQL Query to return a count of a data found in multiple rows and columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

This is a sample data.
I want to return the count of the number of people in the dataset where the first gender is male, and their vegetarian status is Yes and then the next gender is also male but answer NO to vegetarian. where their country of origin is USA

| ID | Gender | Vegetarian | Country_Origin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Male | No | Italy |
| 2 | Female | Yes | USA |
| 3 | Male | Yes | USA |
| 4 | Male | No | USA |

I tried using the Lead function. But it was giving out errors.

Comment: The tags make little sense here. Please correct them and tag what is relevant to your question.

Comment: *I tried using the Lead function. But it was giving out errors*: please show us what you have tried, and the error(s) that you faced.

Comment: Please specify what you mean with *the next gender.*